# Spring Security standard table fields VS Hibernate required fields

Tags: hibernate, spring-security, structure, field

Is it acceptable to make changes to standard `Spring Security` table fields?
http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/appendix-schema.html

In, particularly, `Hibernate` required me to add `id` field for these tables:

```
users

authorities
```

exception:

```
org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): model.Authorities
```

That means,that I should add id fields to my model beans and following config to `*hbm.xml`:

```
 <id name="id">
            <generator class="assigned"/>
 </id>
```

What is the best practice?
Should I change Spring Security DB table structure or somehow deal with Hibernate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine as long as SQL queries issued by [`JdbcDaoImpl`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/jdbc/JdbcDaoImpl.html) are not affected. And even if you need to change these queries, you can do it by configuring `JdbcDaoImpl` appropriately.

However, perhaps it would be better to create a custom implementation of [`UserDetailsService`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html) that would reuse your DAOs to load user information, and configure Spring Security to use it as

```
<security:authentication-provider user-service-ref = "..." />
```